# delete message without read using Pop3 Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had connected to the **gmail using Pop3 Client**.is their any possibility to delete mails from a particular mail id without open the mail? helpful response will be appreciated.

Comment: is it possible to delete mail using pop3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim pop3Client As Pop3Client
Dim i As Integer =1
pop3Client = New Pop3Client
pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, True)
pop3Client.Authenticate("myname@gmail.com", "mypassword")
Dim inbox_count As Integer = pop3Client.GetMessageCount
Do While (inbox_count >= i)
Dim message As Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(i)
If message.Headers.From.Address.ToString = "XXXXXX@XXXX.com" then
 pop3Client.DeleteMessage(i) 
End if
i=i+1
Loop
```